# Show that the integral surface is sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

[image]
I need help in the following problem (exercise 3.13 Do Carmo- Differential Forms and Applications):

> Let $\omega$ be differential 1-form given by $\omega=xdx+ydy+zdz$, and let $P$ be the field of planes in $R^3-{0}$ determined by $\omega$. Show that the integral surface of $P$ passing through $p=(x, y, z)$ is the sphere with center in the origin and passing through $p$.

Where differential 1-form is defined as follows:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to start! I'm new in this topic.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Presumably there is a definition of _plane determined by a one-form_ somewhere in the book, and the book's index would be one place to check. But that said, what to you is a _one-form_ such as $x\, dx + y\, dy + z\, dz$? (There are many ways to interpret these objects, and any attempt to answer should start where you're at.)

Comment: I don't get it, If you can elaborate more please.

Comment: Andrew is pointing out there are different definitions for what a form $\omega$ is. We do not know which definition your course is using, which makes it difficult to for us to explain anything to you, because we might use a different definition. So you need to do two things: first, look up the definition of "field of planes" in your book, If you still don't understand what it means, tell us what is confusing you about that definition. Second, look up how your book defines a "1-form" and edit your question to include that, so we know where you are coming from.

Comment: OK, thank you. I edited the post hope its better know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer is given in the question, you can do the converse (which is easier) and check that the sphere is indeed an integral surface of the plane field. You can do this using implicit differentiation on the Cartesian equation of the sphere.

One way you could have seen this coming is to introduce a metric, which using duality, allows you to identify a $1-$form and a vector, which would point normal to the hyperplane. In this case, the dual vector field is simply the position vector, so you're trying to find a surface whose tangent planes are normal to the position vector from the origin.

In general, if you're trying to find the equation of the surface $z=f(x,y)$, this amounts to solving this system of partial differential equations:
$$
f\partial_xf= -x
$$
$$
f\partial_yf= -y
$$

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Why the 0 is excluded ( let P be the field of planes in R3−0)?

Comment: What will happen if $\omega=zdx+xdy+ydz$ ?

Comment: It’s because the $1-$form is null at the origin if you try to extend it to $0$, so it doesn’t define a hyperplane. More generally, you’ll see that the “limit hyperplane” you’d get at the origin will depend on the direction you took (it may not even converge), so there is no natural choice. Intuitively, the sphere degenerate to a point at the origin so you see the problem coming.

Comment: You won’t have integral surfaces. I’m sure that your book will mention this in the next chapters. It’s due to Froebenius’ integrability condition.